# Int64 usage: difference between pandas array and Series (Pandas version 0.24)

Tags: pandas, numpy, integer, nan, dtype

Yesterday I noticed a Pandas wrinkle that might be worth mentioning. The method `.astype('Int64')` behaves very differently with Pandas Series and Pandas arrays.

In Pandas 0.24, it is possible to assign missing values to integer variables without promoting them to floats.  This is done by using dtype "Int64", which is shorthand for `Int64Dtype()` in the functions that create series.

I want a function that will receive a string and then do the minimal promotion necessary to convert it to integer or number (if possible).  If the string data is ["1", "2", "3", np.nan] it will create Int64, or if ["1.1", "2", "3", np.nan] it will create float64. This is very similar to work done by Pandas builtin `infer_objects` except that instead of using "int64" for data that can be seen as integers, I need "Int64".  If input cannot be converted to `float` or `Int64`, then I want character string to come out. If object is currently a float, I'm happy if
it gracefully changes to Int64 without loss of information.

Here is my effort:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def string_promote(x):
    """Minimum promotion of string to numeric, preserving missing values".

    Convert x to number if possible, using lowest compatible storage type. Prefers
    integer, using pandas Int64Dtype because that preserves missing values.   
    """
    try:
        y = x.astype('Int64')
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        try:
            y = x.astype('float')
        except:
            y = x.astype('object')
    return y
```

This works well if the input is a pandas Series object, as you see here:

```
In [9]: x1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4, np.nan, 4.4])

In [10]: string_promote(x1)
Out[10]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    NaN
5    4.4
dtype: float64

In [11]: x2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4, np.nan, 65])

In [12]: string_promote(x2)
Out[12]: 
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4    NaN
5     65
dtype: Int64


In [15]: x5 = pd.Series([1, 3, 5, 66, 88], dtype='float64')

In [16]: string_promote(x5)
Out[16]: 
0     1
1     3
2     5
3    66
4    88
dtype: Int64
```

All of these examples work as intended.

However, I wondered what would happen if somebody used a Pandas array object with this function, and the output is, well, a complete fail. Maybe total disaster is more accurate The floats are rounded down to int and the `np.nan` turns to machine min, or something like it:

```
In [13]: x3 = pd.array([1, 2, 3, 4.5, np.nan])

In [14]: string_promote(x3)
Out[14]: 
array([                   1,                    2,                    3,
                          4, -9223372036854775808])
```

It seems to me that `.astype('Int64')` should throw an exception if it is not intended for an numpy array or pandas array object.

I'm thinking about ways to fix this. Because I'm new at Pandas, I feel unsure about the correct approach.

I know I'm not the first person to discover this. I notice in the Pandas source code (`io.parsers`) that there is a function called `_validate_integer()` and it appears to be doing the work of checking for this problem I've described here. It is checking safety before trying to coerce a variable to integer. That function is not safe for Int64's using np.nan, but it is going in the direction where I need to end up.

```
In [25]: x4 = pd.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
In [26]: [pd.io.parsers._validate_integer(name="fred", val = i) for i in x4]
Out[26]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [27]: x5 = pd.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5.1])
In [28]: [pd.io.parsers._validate_integer(name="fred", val = i) for i in x5]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e90d15827cfc> in <module>
----> 1 [pd.io.parsers._validate_integer(name="fred", val = i) for i in x5]

<ipython-input-28-e90d15827cfc> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [pd.io.parsers._validate_integer(name="fred", val = i) for i in x5]

~/LinuxDownloads/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _validate_integer(name, val, min_val)
    367         if is_float(val):
    368             if int(val) != val:
--> 369                 raise ValueError(msg)
    370             val = int(val)
    371         elif not (is_integer(val) and val >= min_val):

ValueError: 'fred' must be an integer >=0
```

That exception should happen. Seems like it should happen with .astype('Int64') as well, but that's another story.

I wonder what you think about this, and if there is a way to make astype('Int64') safe for arrays.

Comment: It appears to the `pd.array` documentation that this a new feature.

Comment: `pd.array([1, 2, 3, 4.5, np.nan], 'Int64')` tells me it `"cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64"`.  It's the `4.5` that's causing problems, not the `nan`.

Comment: x.astype('Int64') does not throw an exception, that's why my function fails to get right answer.  But do you think it should? @hpaulj

Comment: `x.astype('Int64')` returns a `ndarray`, with `int64` dtype,  It just calls `np.array` on itself.  `x.to_numpy()` is similar, though I see it references `x._ndarray` property.  These `pd.arrays` (there are several types) appear to be a new extension, something closer to `ndarray` than `Series`, but still holding on to a number of `pandas` features.

Comment: I can't tell if you are disagreeing with me :)  I see same manual you do.  Seems to me that `x.astype("Int64")` should cause an exception because "Int64" is not a valid type for pd.array or ndarray. Instead, what I get out of that is an "int64" which does not have the special qualities we expect, not same message you see with `pd.array` in your previous example. `astype` rounds floats.  So I'm inclined to say it is a bug in Pandas, but, as you say, these are new features.

Comment: Looks like the key difference between `astype` for a `Series` is that it returns a `Series`.  For a `PandasArray` it returns `ndarray`.

Comment: One option is to test: `isinstance(x, pd.core.arrays.base.ExtensionArray)`.  If True, then use `pd.array(x, 'Int64')` rather than `x.astype('Int64').   But the result is an `IntegerArray` which doesn't inherit from `ExtensionArray`.  I don't understand these `pd.array` classes well enough to suggest a better test.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I revised the function to avoid the problem when pd.array input is used rather than a pd.Series.

```
def infer_types(x):
    """Minimum promotion of string to numeric, preserving missing values".

    This is a Goldilocks function, looking for value type that is just
    right. It converts string or float to Int64 if possible without
    losing information. Preserves missing values, using Int64, which
    is only possible in pandas 0.24 or later. If that fails, it
    converts to float64 if possible.

    Similar in purpose to Pandas method "infer_objects", except that it
    preserves missing values for integer with Int64.

    :param x: an input vector. Must be a pandas.Series object or something that
    pd.Series() can convert to a Pandas Series.

    Examples
    --------
    # works as intended with pd.Series

    x1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4.5, np.nan])
    infer_types(x1)

    x2 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan])
    infer_types(x2)

    x3 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan], dtype = "float64")
    infer_types(x4)

    # Array input also succeeds, will be coerced to pd.Series inside function
    x4 = pd.array([1, 2, 3, 4.5])
    infer_types(x4)
    """
    if not isinstance(x, pd.Series):
        try:
            x = pd.Series(x)
        except:
            msg = "Failed to create Pandas Series from input"
            raise ValueError(msg)
    try:
        y = x.astype('Int64')
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        try:
            y = x.astype('float')
        except:
            y = x.astype('object')
    return y
```

I expect that the insertion of Int64 as a type in Pandas .24 will cause revisions in other methods in future.  The current infer_objects() method is not aware of Int64. If it did, it would solve perfectly the problem I've stumbled across.

The only other reasonable strategy is to raise an exception from the outset if the input is not a pd.Series, but now I'm compromising by trying to coerce if I give it something else.  Current version works if input is either pd.array or a raw Python list like [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan].